# image not sticking at the bottom of the display with row and col class

Tags: html, css, web, web-development-server

My output is -
[image]
as you can see, i have two rows, row left has the heading with select your hero moment text and carousel and row right has an image of a player. currently the player is floating in that row. I want to show the image sticked at the bottom of my display in that row.

My html-

```
            <img  src="images/CV.png" width="100%" style="position: -webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;" id="my" alt="" >

          </div>
```

as you can see i have tried the sticky position solution but didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. Kindly change the width and height based on your need.

```css
#my{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
          <div>
<p>
"Aeroplane" redirects here. For other uses, see Airplane (disambiguation) and Aeroplane (disambiguation).

North American P-51 Mustang, a World War II fighter aircraft

The first flight of an airplane, the Wright Flyer on December 17, 1903

An All Nippon Airways Boeing 777-300 taking off from New York JFK Airport
An airplane or aeroplane (informally plane) is a powered, fixed-wing aircraft that is propelled forward by thrust from a jet engine, propeller or rocket engine. Airplanes come in a variety of sizes, shapes, and wing configurations. The broad spectrum of uses for airplanes includes recreation, transportation of goods and people, military, and research. Worldwide, commercial aviation transports more than four billion passengers annually on airliners[1] and transports more than 200 billion tonne-kilometers[2] of cargo annually, which is less than 1% of the world's cargo movement.[3] Most airplanes are flown by a pilot on board the aircraft, but some are designed to be remotely or computer-controlled such as drones.

The Wright brothers invented and flew the first airplane in 1903, recognized as "the first sustained and controlled heavier-than-air powered flight".[4] They built on the works of George Cayley dating from 1799, when he set forth the concept of the modern airplane (and later built and flew models and successful passenger-carrying gliders).[5] Between 1867 and 1896, the German pioneer of human aviation Otto Lilienthal also studied heavier-than-air flight. Following its limited use in World War I, aircraft technology continued to develop. Airplanes had a presence in all the major battles of World War II. The first jet aircraft was the German Heinkel He 178 in 1939. The first jet airliner, the de Havilland Comet, was introduced in 1952. The Boeing 707, the first widely successful commercial jet, was in commercial service for more than 50 years, from 1958 to at least 2013.
</p>
          <img  src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" width="100%"  id="my" alt="" >

          </div>
```

Comment: hey man, thanks a lot for your reply. But i wrote id part for animation of the image. The image has an animation of pulsating when opening the page. So I dont know if same ID can be used in the css anymore :/ should i try still?
Also i resized my browser and ran your code, but it doesnt seem to be responsive :/